# For reversing a number in C++ which ends with zeros

Tags: c++

I want to write a program for reversing a number. For reversing a number like 2300 to 32 so that the ending zeros are not printed, I found this method:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
       int l;
       cin>>l;
       bool leading = true;
       while (l>0)
       {
           if ((l%10==0)&& (leading==true))
           {
               l /= 10;
               leading = false;    // prints 032 as output
               continue;
           }
        //   leading = false;   this prints correct 32
           cout<<l%10;
           l /= 10;
       }
       
       return 0;
}
```

The instruction of assigning boolean leading false inside the if statement is not giving a valid answer, but I suppose assigning it false should give 32 as output whether we give it outside or inside if statement as its purpose is just to make it false once you get the last digit to be a non zero.
Please tell the reason of difference in outputs.

Comment: Your current program is taking a string input, converting it to int, reversing the int, and then converting that back to a string.  Just skip the conversions; read a string, reverse it and discard the leading zeroes.

Comment: If this is just a toy sample, and you actually have an int that you want to reverse, it's probably best to convert it to a string first!  Don't bother trying to work with the integer directly.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `if ((l%10==0)&& (leading==true))` should be written `if (l%10==0 && leading)`. I've removed the redundant parentheses and the redundant comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the difference in output is because when you make `leading = false` inside the `if` statement, you are making it `false` right after encountering the first zero. When you encounter the remaining zeroes, `leading` will be false and you will be printing it.

When you make `leading = false` outside the `if` statement, you are basically waiting till you encounter all zeroes before making it `false`.

If you are looking to reverse a number, this is the well known logic to do so:

```
int reverse(int n)
{
    int r;          //remainder
    int rev = 0;    //reversed number
    
    while(n != 0) 
    {
        r = n%10;
        rev = rev*10 + r;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return rev;
}
```

### EDIT:

The above code snippet is fine if you just want to understand the logic to reverse a number. But if you want to implement the logic anywhere you have to make sure you handle integer overflow problems (the reversed number could be too big to be stored in an integer!!).
The following code will take care of integer overflow:

```
int reverse(int n)
{
    int r;          //remainder
    int rev = 0;    //reversed number
    
    while(n != 0) 
    {
        r = n%10;
        if(INT_MAX/10 < rev)
        {
            cout << "Reversed number too big for an int.";
            break;
        }
        else if(INT_MAX-r < rev*10)
        {
            cout << "Reversed number too big for an int.";
            break;
        }
        rev = rev*10 + r;
        n /= 10;
    }
    if(n != 0)
    {
        //could not reverse number
        //take appropriate action
    }
    return rev;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now I got it.

Answer (score 2):

First, rewrite without `continue` to make the flow clearer,

```
while (l > 0)
{
    if ((l % 10 == 0) && (leading == true))
    {
        l /= 10;
        leading = false;    // prints 032 as output
    }
    else
    {
        //   leading = false;   this prints correct 32
        cout << l % 10;
        l /= 10;
    }
}
```

and move the division common to both branches out of the conditional,

```
while (l > 0)
{
    if ((l % 10 == 0) && (leading == true))
    {
        leading = false;    // prints 032 as output
    }
    else
    {
        //   leading = false;   this prints correct 32
        cout << l % 10;
    }
    l /= 10;
}
```

and now you see that the only difference between the two is the condition under which the assignment `leading = false` happens.

The correct version says, "If this digit is non-zero or a non-leading zero, remember that the next digit is not a leading zero, and print this digit. Then divide."
Your broken version says, "If this is a leading zero, the next digit is not a leading zero." which is pretty obviously not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this ,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, reversedNumber = 0, remainder;

    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> n;

    while(n != 0) {
        remainder = n%10;
        reversedNumber = reversedNumber*10 + remainder;
        n /= 10;
    }

    cout << "Reversed Number = " << reversedNumber;

    return 0;
}
```

Working for me...

Comment: Indeed, there could be a lot of different ways to solve, but I wanted to know the reason of that particular output due to difference in the way of writing boolean expression as false.

Answer (score 0):

When reversing digits of numbers or generally when working with digits and the actual
value does not matter then treating the number as an array of digits is simpler than working with the whole `int`. How to treat a number as an array of digits conveniently? `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int reverse_number(int x) {
    std::string xs = std::to_string(x);
    std::string revx{ xs.rbegin(),xs.rend()};
    std::stringstream ss{revx};
    int result;
    ss >> result;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << reverse_number(123) << "\n";
    std::cout << reverse_number(1230) << "\n";
}
```

`std::to_string` converts the `int` to a `std::string`. `std::string revx{ xs.rbegin(),xs.rend()};` constructs the reversed string by using reverse iterators, and eventually a stringstream can be used to parse the number. Output of the above is:

```
321
321
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but it would be great if you could please tell the reason why using the boolean method s not giving the right output.

Comment: @user17373135 yeah actually a good answer should explain that. The thing is, i don't understand your code, its too complicated for me. Can you explain why it should produce correct output? (if you can't then chances are high that it isnt correct)

Comment: Actually I have a used a boolean expression which I assigned as true and later if the last digit that I come across is 0, and as its the first time loop is moving I assigned the boolean expression false for the next time to indicate that it is not the first zero anymore.